# Type introspection in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a function in `mysql` that tells what type the evaluated expression/column/literal is **in a query**? I don't mean the information schema, but something like:

```
SELECT
    TYPE('Washington') as literal_type,
    TYPE(IF(col='a', col, 2)) as expression_type,
    TYPE(col) as col_type
FROM table
```

And I would get something llike:

```
VARCHAR      --      INT64          --      DATE
```

This is mainly for debugging purposes.

Comment: No, there isn't AFAIK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no function for what you're describing.

The closest thing to what you're talking about is using the MySQL client with the `--column-type-info` option to display result set metadata.

But that wouldn't help you if you're using SQL programmatically.

```
mysql> select 'Washington' as literal_type, if(d = 9, d, 2) as expression_type, t as col_type from mytable;
```

Output:

```
Field   1:  `literal_type`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       VAR_STRING
Collation:  utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci (255)
Length:     40
Max_length: 10
Decimals:   31
Flags:      NOT_NULL 

Field   2:  `expression_type`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   ``
Table:      ``
Org_table:  ``
Type:       LONGLONG
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     20
Max_length: 1
Decimals:   0
Flags:      BINARY NUM 

Field   3:  `col_type`
Catalog:    `def`
Database:   `test`
Table:      `mytable`
Org_table:  `mytable`
Type:       DATE
Collation:  binary (63)
Length:     10
Max_length: 10
Decimals:   0
Flags:      BINARY 


+--------------+-----------------+------------+
| literal_type | expression_type | col_type   |
+--------------+-----------------+------------+
| Washington   |               2 | 2020-11-21 |
+--------------+-----------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: thanks, how do you add in the `--column-type-info` in the query? In your query I don't see any additional statements.

Comment: It's not part of an SQL query. It's an option on the command line for the mysql client. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html